# What is the recommened way to store API keys and secrets in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app

For a UWP app what is the recommend mechanism for storing secrets that need to be deployed with an app such as API keys and secret tokens? For user generated auth tokens [PasswordVault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) makes sense but I can't see a way to set those as part of app deployment. Up until now I have them embedded in the app which doesn't seem "correct" or safe.

Comment: For windows 8.1 I used to created .dll which would store the required info and add them as resource. Now planning on using cryptography and storing data in file which can be decrypted inside app and accessed so that even if someone was to access the file from local storage they wont be able to access data. Though you do get option of `Keycredential` and `Identity` but these come in use once a user logins.

Comment: @Jerin I've considered that but then it seems like you just move the problem. How do you protect your decryption key?

Comment: The decryption key would be added as a constant in your code or as .dll resource. Unless somebody hacks your code they wont be able to find the encryption algo used and the decryption key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PasswordCredential` api, code snippet:

```
string CredentialsName = "testing";
private PasswordCredential GetCredentialFromLocker()
{
    PasswordCredential credential = null;

    var vault = new PasswordVault();
    IReadOnlyList<PasswordCredential> credentialList = null;
    try
    {
        credentialList = vault.FindAllByUserName(Username);
    }
    catch
    {
        return credential;
    }
    if (credentialList.Count > 0)
    {
        credential = credentialList[0];
    }

    return credential;
}

public void CreatePassword(string password, string username)
{
    var vault = new PasswordVault();
    vault.Add(new PasswordCredential(CredentialsName, username, password));

}
```